# Optimize PowerShell code to avoid calling the cmdlet multiple times inside calculated properties?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am looking to optimize the code below to avoid calling the same command twice under the calculated properties.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvmsize

```
Get-AzVM | Select-Object-Object Name,
    @{ l = 'osdiskingb'; e = { ($_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB) } }, `
    @{ l = 'memory'; e = { $size = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize; Get-AzVMSize -vmname $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $size } | Select-Object -expand MemoryInMB } }, `
    @{ l = 'cpu'; e = { $size = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize; Get-AzVMSize -vmname $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $size } | Select-Object -expand NumberOfCores } }, `
    @{ l = 'nic'; e = { $_.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.id.split('/') | Select-Object -Last 1 } }, `
    @{ l = 'ip'; e = { $nic = $_.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.id.split('/') | Select-Object -Last 1; Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name $nic | Select-Object -expand ipconfigurations | Select-Object -expand privateipaddress } }
```

The script above works for pulling various different Azure VMs.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not exactly answer your original question, but you might consider dropping calculated properties when the code becomes too complicated. Instead, use a `[pscustomobject]@{…}` literal in a `ForEach-Object` script block. This way you can move common code out of the properties to the begin of the script block.

```sh
Get-AzVM | ForEach-Object {
    $size = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
    $vmsize = Get-AzVMSize -vmname $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $size }
    $nic = $_.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.id.split('/') | Select-Object -Last 1

    # Implicitly outputs an object with the given properties
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name       = $_.Name
        osdiskingb = $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
        memory     = $vmsize.MemoryInMB
        cpu        = $vmsize.NumberOfCores
        nic        = $nic
        ip         = (Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name $nic).ipconfigurations.privateipaddress  
    } 
}
```

On a side note, `SomeCommand | Select-Object -Expand PropertyName` isn't very efficient and can be replaced by member access, as I did for the `ip` property. The key is to enclose the command in parentheses.

Comment: That's great, tha nkyou @zett42 for your sharing and explanation.

Comment: would you be able to help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403990/powershell-to-list-all-azure-vm-data-disk-size-confusion ?

Answer (score 4):

Note:

- This answer addresses the question *as asked*, in the context of `Select-Object` and calculated properties.
- For a `ForEach-Object`-based alternative that uses explicit construction of `[pscustomobject]` instances, see [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73391560/45375).

---

While the script blocks of [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) are executed in sequence, for each input object, they each run in their own *child* scope relative to the caller, which complicates sharing state between them.

However, you can simply create a variable whose value you want to share in the *parent* scope, which in the simplest case inside a script is the `$script:` scope, as the following simplified example shows (which uses a call to `Get-Date` in lieu of a call to Azure cmdlet as an example of a call you do not want to repeat):

```
# Share the result of the `Get-Date` call between calculated properties.
'foo' | Select-Object `
  @{ n='Month'; e = { $script:dt = Get-Date; $dt.Month } },
  @{ n='Year'; e = { $dt.Year } }
```

Output:

```
Month Year
----- ----
    8 2022
```

This proves that the `$script:`-scoped `$dt` variable was successfully used in the second calculated property.

If you want to reliably target the *parent* scope, which may differ from the `$script:` scope if you're running inside a nested function call, for instance, replace `$script:dt = Get-Date` with 
`Set-Variable -Scope 1 dt (Get-Date)`

Note:

- That script blocks of calculated properties as well as delay-bind script blocks run in a *child* scope may be surprising, given that it contrasts with the behavior of script blocks passed to `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object`, for instance - for a discussion, see [GitHub issue #7157](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7157).